# Convert SQL query to pandas logic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7

I have the below sql query. I should achieve the same logic in python.
Count of id with where condition divided by count of id with another where condition

```
"count(ticket_id)*100  where ticket_status='PENDING'/count(ticket_id) where ticket_status in ('COMPLETED','CREATED','IN-PROGRESS')"
```

Any help would be appreciatable!!

Comment: What SQL dialect (SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, ...) is that? I don't think it's valid SQL in any dialect I know

Comment: '/' represents divided by @navaneethnanda

Comment: how can word 'pending' be divided by count(ticket id) i think you mistakenly merged two queries

Answer (score 1):

if you have a dataframe named interactions

for this part of query you mentioned since it seems valid till there

```
count(ticket_id)*100 from  interactions where ticket_status='PENDING'
```

python part

```
interactions[interactions['ticket_status'=='PENDING']].count()*100
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks odd but is this what you are looking for?

```
out = (interactions.loc[interactions['ticket_status'] == 'PENDING', 'ticket_id'].count() * 100 / 
       interactions.loc[interactions['ticket_status'].isin(('COMPLETED','CREATED','IN-PROGRESS')), 'ticket_id'].count()
      )
```